# Torque: How lock node cores to one application

Tags: torque, pbs

I am having an issue that I do not know how to solve.  Say I have 2 nodes (node1 and node2) each with 24 cores, I have software where I have a license for 32 cores. I want to be able to configure node1 to ONLY accept jobs for that software, and I want node2 to reserve 8 cores out of its'24 to be exclusively for that software, but the remaining 16 be free for any other program to use.  Is there a nice way to do this in Torque? I think I can find a way to deal with node1 by defining node properties, but I can't figure out a way to allocate node2 as needed. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks

Comment: As Danila points out below, you can use cpuset to set the task scheduler affinity for one particular core.  HOWEVER, why do you think you're better at managing a processor's time than the kernel scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Torque, but I had similar task which I resolved with tweaking "cpuset" for Condor. You might look into that and find something helpful for your task (user space shielding e.t.c.)

https://code.google.com/p/cpuset/